# Used with mybatis ibatis

Tags: java, gradle, mybatis, ibatis

I am managing mybatis version via gradle.

So far, we are using implementation 'org.mybatis:mybatis:2.3.5' version, which uses ibatis syntax.

But from now on, it seems that the implementation 'org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.7' version should be used together.

Is it possible to use both versions at the same time?

If you delete version 2.3.5 and use version 3.5.7, existing sources will cause errors.

So, I left the existing source and asked to add a new version and use it.

Is it possible?

If it is not possible, do I have to modify the source by upgrading the version?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL0o4.png)

Comment: I've never tried using both iBATIS 2.x and MyBatis 3.x in the same project and don't know if it's possible or not. To upgrade, you may have to modify some code. For XML mappers, there are a few user contributed helper tools [1](https://github.com/mybatis/ibatis2mybatis) [2](https://github.com/ogasada/ibatisToMyBatis3).

Comment: @ave I have had success using both versions.

One is referring to the version with gradle and the other version is directly put into the lib file as a jar and built. Both versions are read and the existing source works without errors, and only the newly added 3 version mapper was added and used separately.

Comment: I have never used a mixed version of MyBatis. Ten years ago, I went though a clean upgrade to MyBatis and got rid of iBatis. Why do you need the old iBatis for? Legacy code? The migration should be simple, anyway.

Comment: @TheImpaler I didn't want to migrate and I wanted an additional mybatis syntax in an old project, so I had to add it.